# Google custom API (&rights parameter) description

Tags: api, google-custom-search, google-search-api, google-image-search

I am using Google custom API for image.

I have to set the parameter to retrieve images having rights for commercial use.

I can see **&rights** parameter and possible values

> cc_publicdomain, cc_attribute, cc_sharealike, cc_noncommercial,
>   cc_nonderived

But not finding it's description. 
Can any one please let me know the link where I can find it's descriptions

Thanks

Comment: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, So I think cc_sharealike allows commercial use with edition. am I right ?

Comment: sharealike means you must publish whatever you create from the original under the same license.

Comment: So which parameter I can use freely similar to ->.RIGHTS_COMMERCIAL_MODIFICATION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making lots googling found

https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Public_domain

https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/uk/

So I am now going to use

> "cc_publicdomain"

https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Public_domain as RIGHTS_COMMERCIAL_MODIFICATION